# I wanted to change the rowHeight of the tableview, while changing orientation Its works in simulator not in Real Devices

Tags: swift, iphone, uitableview

If I change the orientation of the phone,I wanted to  change the rowHeight of the tableview. its work in simulator not in Real Device
Anyone help me to solve this issue
Thank you

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{
            printer.isEnabled = true
            
            return 140
        }else{
            return 90
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide relevant code to show us what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: @Demented07 I Attached my code Please give any Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with either your `tableViewDelegate` or with your `tableViewDataSource` these both have to be set to the current view controller (the table view's view controller) the `Delegate` is the thing which handles events such as touches etc and the `dataSource` places the data into the table view's rows and sections.

If you are **NOT** using a `UITableViewController` and instead are using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` added on it as a sub view then you need to do these two things:
(you can place this in `viewDidLoad()` or wherever else you feel is best, make sure to place it inside of an appropriate view controller life-cycle method or it will not be executed properly).

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

An alternative to doing that is using a `UITableViewController` which you drag out directly from inside of interface builder (This already has the `delegate` and `dataSource` hooked up to itself therefore you do not have to set it yourself in code.):
[image: Table View Controller Screenshot]

Your code worked for me with one of those:
(Using this method also requires your view controller to inherit from `UITableViewController` as shown below).

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController { 

    // Other data source methods such as cell for row at etc...

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{
            print("row height: 140") // Test
            return 140
        } else {
            print("row height: 90") // Test
            return 90
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot that you said it worked in the sim but not on a physical device. I'll test it on a physical device now and see if I get any, problems and then try to work out what could be causing it for you.

Comment: Ok so I've tested it on physical device and for me it works just the same as it did on the sim, the height of the table view cells change to the specified amount. I'm not entirely sure why it was working on your sim and not your device. (Maybe use print statements to ensure that it is/isn't working how you are expecting). Hopefully you're able to fix the problem now if not please comment back.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I am using the table as a sub View . I already did the same as you suggested but it still not working in physical device . Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I’ll have one final go at this later on today once I’m free. if you could include all of you table view methods (all delegate and data source ones) that might be very useful thank you.